# How do I encrypt the passwords in my database if I need to decrypt the password into plaintext?

Tags: java, mysql, encryption, hash, cryptography

I'm creating a system which stores a list of username and passwords in the database and uses them to login to some sites and do some tasks.
I want to store the passwords in a secure way in the database. With my limited understanding of hashing, I know its not something I can use since I need to get the plain text back later. Also I heard storing encrypted passwords in database is a bad practice. So what approach can I take ?

Comment: Storing encrypted password is great, but a decrypting it is not great. So instead of having a forgot password that decrypt your encrypted password in the database, make user to reset it and generate another password.

Comment: Its better to save the passwords Hashes in the database than to store the encrypted password because even if your  database is hacked, The hacker cannot see the original password. Why do you want the passwords in plain text anyway?

Comment: Once I store the password, I'll retrieve it at a later time and then use it to login to a email website through my system. Can I just send the hashcode to the website? Say If I'm loggin into gmail through this sytem, how will  I do it If I store the password as hashes?

Comment: He's not storing passwords for users -- **HE** is the user and the passwords are being use for his app to login to _other_ systems -- so the plaintext must be recoverable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you answered your question yourself:

If you need to store useraname/password so that users can authenticate to your app, the recommended way is to store the hash of the password. This way, even if your database is compromised, passwords can't be recovered.

But your scenario is different. You want to store a list of username/password to access other sites. As you said, you must be able to get them back in plaintext. Encryption seems to be the only way.

That's the same issue faced with all [password managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_manager): your list of password is as secure as the "master" password you use to manage the list.

Comment: I think you are the only one who understood the question..Maybe I should have explained better.

Comment: So If I'm sending the plain text to the mail server, won't it be easy to sniff it out or something ? Is there a universal way to encrypt outgoing passwords or is it server dependent?

Comment: @user2067771 For more security, you can use an SSL connection (i.e. encrypted) to connect to the other server. That's like logging to website with your username/password in plain text, but using HTTPS to prevent sniffing.

Comment: I am in fact using SSL. Thanks.

Comment: @user2067771 - Encrypting the passwords is the only choice you have. The problem is where to store the key, at least the application must be able to read the stored passwords. One safe way to solve this problem is, to encrypt the passwords, but not to store the key. The user will have to provide the key everytime he want's to use your service, this may be applicable or not. Maybe he logs in to your service (now you have the key), and only then the other accounts are accessed. One problem is, that you cannot implement a lost key function this way.

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot seem to imagine which use might this have for passwords, you can easily use MySQL's [AES encryption-decryption functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt). It would be better if you could use a unique key for each user.

Comment: As far as i know, MySql's encryption functions are very weak, because they do not provide an IV vector (only EBC mode). The main problem, where you should store the key, is is still open.

Answer (score -1):

You might try this

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;

import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class EncryptUtil {
private static final byte[] SALT = {
    (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x12,
    (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x12,
};

private static String encrypt(String property, char[] password) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(password));
    Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, 20));
    return base64Encode(pbeCipher.doFinal(property.getBytes("UTF-8")));
}

private static String base64Encode(byte[] bytes) {
        // NB: This class is internal, and you probably should use another impl
        return new BASE64Encoder().encode(bytes);
    }

    public static String encryptPassword(String username, String password) throws     UnsupportedEncodingException, GeneralSecurityException{
        char[] pwChar = password.toCharArray();
        String encryptedPassword = encrypt(username, pwChar);
        return encryptedPassword;
    }
}
```

Then just call the function `encryptPassword()`

Comment: Question clearly states "... if I need to decrypt the password into plain text".  How does this answer the question?